# Import javascript function from another file with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This is a noob question. I've been developing in React for a while now and I'm used to breaking up my code into components.

I've started a new project using puppeteer.js. I'd like to break my javascript function up into components as well but I have no idea how to import a function from another file.

Is this possible?

Path: `main.js`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
import {myFunction} from './myFunction.js';

(async function main() {
  try {
    // launch puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    // open browser
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({}); 

    const callMyFunction = await myFunction(page);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("our error", e);
  }
})();
```

Path: `myFunction.js`

```
async function myFunction(page) {
  console.log('this function has been imported');
  return true;
}

export default myFunction;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
//myFunction.js
async function myFunction(page) {
  console.log('this function has been imported');
  return true;
}
module.exports = myFunction;
```

```
//main.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const myFunction = require('./myFunction');

(async function main() {
  try {
    // launch puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    // open browser
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({}); 

    const callMyFunction = await myFunction(page);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("our error", e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: It wouldn't work without relative path. I've updated it.